# Other way of displaying image, when only having the link from php

Tags: php, html, forms, image

I am making a tool to convert steam profile urls to the different steam ids, whatever.
I have the different functions, triggered when submitting the URL of the profile with a form.

One of the function are, that it gets the avatar of the regarding steam profile. 
Actually it gets the link of the image. What I can do is, echo an img element with the link, this wont give me any flexibility since I wont be really able to style etc that afterwards.
Now, the function of getting the avatar, is in the function of the submit form.

I tried just inserting the image URL into an img element.

```
<img src"<?php echo $avatar ?>">
```

Well, then I get a error message, saying "$avatar" is undefined, even though I defined it in my main php tags. I think that is due to the fact that it is done inside the form function, could be wrong though.

My main question now is, what could be a different approach to this? I need that in the form function because it should only be called then. 
Maybe I just have to use the inconvenient way of echoing an img element every time.

Here is the actual code.

```
 <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="profile_url">
      <input type="submit" value="click" name="submit">
 </form>
 <div id="avatar-div" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
 <img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>">
 </div>
```

the main php part

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  display();
} 

function display() {
 require_once 'steamid.class.php';
 $input = $_POST["profile_url"];
 $api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 $id = new SteamID($input,$api_key);


if(substr_count($input, ' ') === strlen($input)) {
    echo "Enter URL";
} else {

    if ($id->resolveVanity()) {

    $avatar = $id->toAvatar();



    $communityid = $id->toCommunityID();
    echo $communityid . ", " . " ";

    $steamid = $id->toSteamID();
    echo $steamid . ", " . " ";

    $userid = '[U:1:'.$id->toUserID().']';
    echo $userid . ", " . " ";
    } else {
        echo "Profile wasnt found!";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're saving the avatar variable in the global scope anywhere. You could return the avatar value from your function or define`$avatar` in the global scope and then use `global $avatar;` in your function.

Comment: Your posted code has 0 instances of `$avatarurl`. Please include the part of code where you believe it is being set.

Comment: @Bijan i edited it, its "$avatar" everywhere, just messed it up, when explaining.

Comment: You haven't provided the needed information for someone to give you an answer. Is your HTML and PHP on the same page? Where do you execute `display()`? Aside from that, as Bijan said you need to give the variable correct scope to access it.

Comment: The HTML and PHP is on the same page, the "display()" is being executed when submitting a form. Currently not sure how to set the variable scope so it is global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm refactoring my answer based on the conversation we had. Here is the recommended PHP code.

```
function urlCheck() {
    $input = $_POST["profile_url"];

    if(empty($input)) {
      echo "Enter URL";

      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
}

function display() {
  require_once 'steamid.class.php';
  $api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  $id = new SteamID($input,$api_key);

  if (urlCheck()) {

    if ($id->resolveVanity()) {

      $communityid = $id->toCommunityID();
      echo $communityid . ", " . " ";

      $steamid = $id->toSteamID();
      echo $steamid . ", " . " ";

      $userid = '[U:1:'.$id->toUserID().']';
      echo $userid . ", " . " ";

      return $id->toAvatar();

    } else {
        echo "Profile wasn't found!";
    }
  }
}
```

You haven't mentioned where you're running `display()`, or where you're expecting the output (echo) to display. I can only assume you want it at the top of the page. Let me explain how to use this.

```
<head>
  $avatar = display();
</head>
<body>
  <div id="avatar-div" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
    <img src="<?= $avatar ?>">
  </div>
</body>
```

Basically the way this works, is that wherever you run `display()`, is where the echoes will output (in this case, before the body). Wherever you echo `$avatar` is where the `id` will be displayed. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this answer, this would work now, but it just inserts every information into the img (all other things in the if statement). Just putting the rerturn after "$avatar" gets assigned wont work either, since it will just stop with the if statement there, and the other information wont be displayed. How could I fix that?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to do too much within the same function. Each function should be simple and perform a specific task. You should have one function to process `$input` and another function to get the profile URL. I suppose a better approach would be to do `$result = display()` then `<img src="<?= $result ?>">` but you would need to know whether a message or the URL was returned which you can't do simply echoing.

Comment: Ok, but waht you are supposing doesnt really make a difference, right? I mean your just making an extra variable or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The best approach with what you have may be using a global, although I've never written code that way and don't agree with it.

Comment: It makes a difference because you could determine what `$result` contains instead of blindly returning/echoing something.

Comment: Tried that before, and it I dont really get it, tried to assign it as a global in many different ways, but still couldnt access it

Comment: Well, so would I just, outside of my "display()" function do, `$result = display()`.

Comment: Let me modify my answer with something that may work better for you.

Comment: Hey, so I used the "$result = display()", img element "display()" and "return $id->toAvatar()" It just displays the same thing again, but not the avatar.

Comment: Posted a new answer.

Comment: Did it the wy you explained, somwhow the whole thing doesnt work now anymore. I updated my question with "display" being called.

Comment: Ok so tried this, it wont work. Dont really understand the thing within the "head", guess ill just leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP's [Variable Scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.

To fix this problem, use the `global` keyword. This way you will explicitly set `$avatar;` as a global variable so it can be used outside of your `display()` function.

Here is how it would work for your example:

```
function display() {
    global $avatar;
    // Rest of your display() function
    // Set $avatar somewhere in here
}

display(); // Actually call display so $avatar is set

<div id="avatar-div" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
 <img src="<?=$avatar;?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so could I do it like, global $avatar = ...... or define it first and then make it global. Because I used the 2nd method and the error still occurs.

Comment: You do not have to set `$avatar` first. At the top of `display()` you would add `global $avatar` and then further down the function, you would set `$avatar` (Don't forget to set avatar URL if profile is not found). I have added an example for you.

Comment: Sadly this still doesnt work, adding it in, when the profile isnt found, results in nothing being displayed. And if I set it as a global  at the top, will sill result in it saying, that it isnt defined. Here is a link of the project. If you open the image icon in a new tab, you can see the error message in the url.[link]https://stemconvtest.000webhostapp.com/test/index.php